# count , group by & Max in php

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, max

I have

```
|name  | number |
|andi  | 40     |
|irfan | 30     |
|lia   | 60     |
|andi  | 50     |
|lia   | 10     |
|sali  | 60     |
```

I want to display like this order by max

```
name   | number |
andi   | 90     |
lia    | 70     |
sali   | 60     |
irfan  | 30     |
```

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(name) 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY name 
ORDER  BY MAX(number)
```

And it's not working. The result just work group by name, and not short by max number

```
name   | number |
lia    | 70     |
sali   | 60     |
andi   | 90     |
irfan  | 30     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `Select * from tablename Order By Number DESC`

Comment: if with code Select * from table name Order By Number DESC
result name not group
i want name show just one not much

Answer (score 0):

You want `sum()` not `count()`:

```
SELECT name, SUM(number)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY SUM(number) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, 
       sum(number) as score
FROM   Test2 
GROUP  BY name 
ORDER  BY score DESC
```

What you have to do is
- Sum the column 'number'
- set it as score
- order it by score DESC

Hope this help you

Comment: The user didn't ask for the *sum* of the scores; they wanted the highest.